# Youtrack create simple client user - with access onlywithin a single project

Tags: user-profile, user-management, youtrack

In YouTrack, has anyone managed to solve the simple problem of adding a user as in any other system, as a simple client?
I'm trying to achieve something very trivial, but I've been trying for 1 week and I haven't found a solution.

What I want to achieve in steps:

1. Creating a new project, for example: My very new project
2. Creating a client profile.The client/buyer who will eventually pay for whom I will work on this project.
3. To allow the client to access only this one project (and no other), to see the KANBAN tables created and assigned only to this single project, where it can create new tickets, comment on existing ones, etc.
4. What would be extra: a solution to prevent the client from creating new Kanban tables and from seeing the notes written for projects, o it only uses youtrack for simple ticket management, where if there is a problem it creates a ticket that we will solve

I couldn't find a solution neither in the documentation, but I don't believe that such a trivial thing can't be solved in a project management software

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly achieve this. You need to grant Issue reader role (here I assume you didn't modify this predefined role) to the user in the project.

I think what you find confusing is that the user still doesn't see the Kanban board you mention. This is because in YouTrack a board's permissions are configured separately from the project permissions. You'll need to set the "Visible to" option of the board accordingly.